# Magnetic buttons are not working properly as they should work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a contact us page for my client, but in that, I made some buttons whose behavior looks like magnetic. I have put these numbers of buttons in two sections i.e. at the top of the form and at the bottom of the form. But the problem is that upper the form buttons work fine until we scroll the page, but below the form, the magnetic buttons are not working as they should have to work.

I have made this page in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Please help me to deliver this project as soon as possible.

```js
    let mouseCursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
    let customCursor = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-cursor');

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', cursor);

    function cursor(e) {
        mouseCursor.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
        mouseCursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    }

    customCursor.forEach(header => {
        header.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            mouseCursor.classList.add("mouse-scale");
        });
        header.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            mouseCursor.classList.remove("mouse-scale");
        });
    });
    
    // ====== DEFAULT DECLARE ====== //
    const buttonsBox = document.querySelectorAll('.button__box');

    // ======BUTTON EVENT====== //
    buttonsBox.forEach(buttonBox => {
        buttonBox.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            const position = buttonBox.getBoundingClientRect();
            //Get the correct position of cursor when hover to the button
            const x = e.pageX - position.left - position.width / 2;
            const y = e.pageY - position.top - position.height / 2;

            //Set the button position
            buttonBox.style.transform = `translate(${x * 0.5}px, ${y * 0.5}px)`;
            //Same thing with the span element
            buttonBox.children[1].style.transform = `translate(${x * 0.3}px, ${y * 0.3}px)`;
        })

        //It change postion but not go back to the original positon, so what we should do
        buttonBox.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            buttonBox.style.transform = `translate(0px, 0px)`;
            //Same thing with the span element
            buttonBox.children[1].style.transform = `translate(0px, 0px)`;
        })
    })
    
    const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        let btn = btns[i];
        btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
            const x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft;
            const y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop;

            btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
            btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
        }
    }
```

```css
/* custom cursor start */
    .cursor {
        position: absolute;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: aliceblue;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition-property: background, transform;
        transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        mix-blend-mode: difference;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .mouse-scale {
        transform: scale(2);
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
    }

    /* custom cursor end */

    .pixelz-home-main-container {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }

    .header-main-container {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }

    .post-main-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: transparent !important;
    }

    .post-main-container .post-sub-container {
        max-width: 1160px !important;
    }

    .services-main-container.budget-main-container {
        margin-top: 5rem;
    }

    .services-main-container .service-title h3 {
        color: #333;
        font-size: 23px;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    }

    /* Magnetic button start */
    .button__container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: 25px;
    }

    .button__box {
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        border-radius: .5rem;
        background: transparent;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 100vw;
        transition: transform .2s linear;
    }

    .button__box input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .services-main-container .button__container .button__box input[type="checkbox"]:checked~span {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .button__box span {
        display: block;
        color: #333;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        pointer-events: none;
        padding: 1.4em 2.6em;
        transition: transform .2s linear;
    }

    /* Magnetic button end */

    .services-main-container .personal-details {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        gap: 36px;
    }

    .services-main-container .personal-details input {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-size: 2.2rem;
        height: 8rem;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        margin: 0px;
        border-style: none none solid;
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        outline: none;
    }

    .services-main-container .personal-details input::placeholder {
        color: #000;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    /* Submit button start */
    form .submit-button {
        margin-top: 6rem;
    }

    form .submit-button {
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 80px 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    form .submit-button .btn {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 19px;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: 'Montserrat';
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 14px 55px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    form .submit-button .btn::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: var(--y);
        left: var(--x);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #000;
        transition: width 0.7s, height 0.7s;
    }

    form .submit-button .btn span {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    form .submit-button .btn:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

    form .submit-button .btn:hover::before {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }

    /* Submit button end */

    /* Footer start */
    .footer-main-container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1520px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 100px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container hr {
        width: 1px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #000;
        margin: 0 5.5%;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content {
        width: calc(100% / 3);
        max-width: 438px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .logo {
        display: flex;
        width: 94px;
        height: 94px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .logo img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .content p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .content p span {
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .imp-links {
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .imp-links ul {
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .imp-links ul li {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .imp-links ul li a {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .imp-links ul li p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .copyright p {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        color: #161733;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links {
        width: calc((100% / 3) - 10%);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: fit-content;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links ul li {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links ul li:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links ul li a span {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media {
        width: calc(100% / 3);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 23px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 23px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title .images {
        display: flex;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title .images a {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: flex;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title .images a:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 22px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title .images a img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 10px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 16px;
        margin: 0;
        color: #161733;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email form {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email form input {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 236px;
        height: 32px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email form input::placeholder {
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email form button {
        border-radius: 0% 40% 40% 0% / 0% 50% 50% 0%;
        width: 65px;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 0;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email form button i {
        color: #eae3f3;
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    /* Footer end */
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>

<div class="pixelz-home-main-container">

        <!-- contact us -->
        <div class="post-main-container">
            <div class="post-sub-container">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="services-main-container">
                        <div class="service-title">
                            <h3>I'm interested in...</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="services button__container">
                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="span">Web Design + Dev</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>Branding</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>Social Media</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>Digital Marketing</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>Influencer Marketing</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="personal-details">
                            <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Your name">
                            <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Your email">
                            <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Tell us about your project">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="services-main-container budget-main-container">
                        <div class="service-title">
                            <h3>Project budget (USD)</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="services button__container">
                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="span">10-20k</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>30-40k</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>40-50k</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>50-100k</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>&#10095;100k</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="submit-button">
                        <button class="btn custom-cursor" type="submit"><span>Send request</span></button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Footer -->
            <div class="footer-main-container">
                <div class="footer-sub-container">
                    <div class="footer-content">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/c-logo.jpeg" alt="Company logo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non, in ea nulla at odit laboriosam animi nam perferendis a, sunt mollitia sapiente nostrum voluptate hic dolorum sed iste odio beatae neque. Consequatur dolore dolores ullam voluptatibus ea, vitae doloremque quas illum vero, cum mollitia magnam quod vel excepturi placeat quisquam.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                More clients and more profits— <span> no outsourcing required! </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="imp-links">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Terms of Use</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <p>&#124;</p>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="copyright">
                            <p>
                                &copy; Lorem, ipsum dolor | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur 2023
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="footer-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Home</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Web Design</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Social Media</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Branding</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Digital Marketing</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Influencer Marketing</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Projects</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Founders Talk</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>About Us</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Work with us</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="footer-social-media">
                        <div class="sm-title">
                            <p>Follow us on</p>
                            <div class="images">
                                <a href=""><img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/tw.svg" alt=""></a>
                                <a href=""><img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/ig.svg" alt=""></a>
                                <a href=""><img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/ln.svg" alt=""></a>
                                <a href=""><img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/dribbble.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sm-email">
                            <p>Subscribe to know our latest blogs</p>
                            <form action="">
                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address">
                                <button type="submit"><i class="bi bi-play-fill"></i></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: what is a magnetic button?

Comment: pay extra attention to the word **minimal** when posting a [repro]. Your code is neither minimal nor reproducible.

Comment: next time I try my best

Comment: @shivanisrivastav You are being asked to *edit* your existing question to be minimal and reproducible.

Comment: FYI, when creating a snippet here, the JavaScript panel takes _only_ JavaScript code, you had `<script>` tags and HTML comments in there, that caused syntax errors. Fixed it for you, so now your snippet at least runs (and we get an idea at least, what a "magnetic button" apparently is supposed to be.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Get the correct position of cursor when hover to the button
const x = e.pageX - position.left - position.width / 2;
const y = e.pageY - position.top - position.height / 2;
```

Despite what the comment says ;-), this is not correctly taking the scroll position into account. The more you scroll down the page, the more your x/y calculation will be off, and the more the buttons will start to misbehave when you translate their position using those values.

Much simpler than calculating the position in relation to the document and its scroll position, is to use the `offsetX` / `offsetY` properties here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX:

> The `offsetX` read-only property of the MouseEvent interface provides the offset in the X coordinate of the mouse pointer between that event and the padding edge of the target node.

So those get you the offset to the top left corner of the button, and all you need to do is subtract half the width/ height from those now, to make your code work fine no matter how far down the buttons might be, or what the exact scroll position of the document is:

```
//Get the correct position of cursor when hover to the button
const x = e.offsetX - (position.width / 2);
const y = e.offsetY - (position.height / 2);
```

```js
let mouseCursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
    let customCursor = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-cursor');

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', cursor);

    function cursor(e) {
        mouseCursor.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
        mouseCursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    }

    customCursor.forEach(header => {
        header.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            mouseCursor.classList.add("mouse-scale");
        });
        header.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            mouseCursor.classList.remove("mouse-scale");
        });
    });
    
    // ====== DEFAULT DECLARE ====== //
    const buttonsBox = document.querySelectorAll('.button__box');

    // ======BUTTON EVENT====== //
    buttonsBox.forEach(buttonBox => {
        buttonBox.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            const position = buttonBox.getBoundingClientRect();
            //Get the correct position of cursor when hover to the button
            const x = e.offsetX - (position.width / 2);
            const y = e.offsetY - (position.height / 2);

            //Set the button position
            buttonBox.style.transform = `translate(${x * 0.5}px, ${y * 0.5}px)`;
            //Same thing with the span element
            buttonBox.children[1].style.transform = `translate(${x * 0.3}px, ${y * 0.3}px)`;
        })

        //It change postion but not go back to the original positon, so what we should do
        buttonBox.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            buttonBox.style.transform = `translate(0px, 0px)`;
            //Same thing with the span element
            buttonBox.children[1].style.transform = `translate(0px, 0px)`;
        })
    })
    
    const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        let btn = btns[i];
        btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
            const x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft;
            const y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop;

            btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
            btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
        }
    }
```

```css
/* custom cursor start */
    .cursor {
        position: absolute;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: aliceblue;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        pointer-events: none;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition-property: background, transform;
        transform-origin: 100% 100%;
        mix-blend-mode: difference;
        z-index: 1000;
    }

    .mouse-scale {
        transform: scale(2);
        width: 35px;
        height: 35px;
    }

    /* custom cursor end */

    .pixelz-home-main-container {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }

    .header-main-container {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }

    .post-main-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: transparent !important;
    }

    .post-main-container .post-sub-container {
        max-width: 1160px !important;
    }

    .services-main-container.budget-main-container {
        margin-top: 5rem;
    }

    .services-main-container .service-title h3 {
        color: #333;
        font-size: 23px;
        font-weight: 400;
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
    }

    /* Magnetic button start */
    .button__container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: 25px;
    }

    .button__box {
        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        border-radius: .5rem;
        background: transparent;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 100vw;
        transition: transform .2s linear;
    }

    .button__box input[type="checkbox"] {
        display: none;
    }

    .services-main-container .button__container .button__box input[type="checkbox"]:checked~span {
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
    }

    .button__box span {
        display: block;
        color: #333;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        pointer-events: none;
        padding: 1.4em 2.6em;
        transition: transform .2s linear;
    }

    /* Magnetic button end */

    .services-main-container .personal-details {
        margin-top: 2rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        gap: 36px;
    }

    .services-main-container .personal-details input {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-size: 2.2rem;
        height: 8rem;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        margin: 0px;
        border-style: none none solid;
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
        outline: none;
    }

    .services-main-container .personal-details input::placeholder {
        color: #000;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    /* Submit button start */
    form .submit-button {
        margin-top: 6rem;
    }

    form .submit-button {
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 80px 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    form .submit-button .btn {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 19px;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: 'Montserrat';
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 14px 55px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    form .submit-button .btn::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: var(--y);
        left: var(--x);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background-color: #000;
        transition: width 0.7s, height 0.7s;
    }

    form .submit-button .btn span {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    form .submit-button .btn:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

    form .submit-button .btn:hover::before {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }

    /* Submit button end */

    /* Footer start */
    .footer-main-container {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1520px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 100px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container hr {
        width: 1px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #000;
        margin: 0 5.5%;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content {
        width: calc(100% / 3);
        max-width: 438px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .logo {
        display: flex;
        width: 94px;
        height: 94px;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .logo img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .content p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .content p span {
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .imp-links {
        padding: 20px 0;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .imp-links ul {
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .imp-links ul li {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .imp-links ul li a {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .imp-links ul li p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-content .copyright p {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        color: #161733;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links {
        width: calc((100% / 3) - 10%);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: fit-content;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links ul li {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links ul li:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-links ul li a span {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media {
        width: calc(100% / 3);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 23px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 23px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title .images {
        display: flex;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title .images a {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        display: flex;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title .images a:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 22px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-title .images a img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 10px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 16px;
        margin: 0;
        color: #161733;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email form {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 300px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email form input {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 236px;
        height: 32px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-top-left-radius: 30px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
        background-color: transparent;
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email form input::placeholder {
        color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email form button {
        border-radius: 0% 40% 40% 0% / 0% 50% 50% 0%;
        width: 65px;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 0;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .footer-main-container .footer-sub-container .footer-social-media .sm-email form button i {
        color: #eae3f3;
        font-size: 35px;
    }

    /* Footer end */
```

```html
<div class="cursor"></div>

<div class="pixelz-home-main-container">

        <!-- contact us -->
        <div class="post-main-container">
            <div class="post-sub-container">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="services-main-container">
                        <div class="service-title">
                            <h3>I'm interested in...</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="services button__container">
                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="span">Web Design + Dev</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>Branding</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>Social Media</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>Digital Marketing</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>Influencer Marketing</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="personal-details">
                            <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Your name">
                            <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Your email">
                            <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Tell us about your project">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="services-main-container budget-main-container">
                        <div class="service-title">
                            <h3>Project budget (USD)</h3>
                        </div>

                        <div class="services button__container">
                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span class="span">10-20k</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>30-40k</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>40-50k</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>50-100k</span>
                            </label>

                            <label class="button__box custom-cursor">
                                <input type="checkbox">
                                <span>&#10095;100k</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="submit-button">
                        <button class="btn custom-cursor" type="submit"><span>Send request</span></button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Footer -->
            <div class="footer-main-container">
                <div class="footer-sub-container">
                    <div class="footer-content">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/c-logo.jpeg" alt="Company logo">
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <p>
                                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Non, in ea nulla at odit laboriosam animi nam perferendis a, sunt mollitia sapiente nostrum voluptate hic dolorum sed iste odio beatae neque. Consequatur dolore dolores ullam voluptatibus ea, vitae doloremque quas illum vero, cum mollitia magnam quod vel excepturi placeat quisquam.
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                More clients and more profits— <span> no outsourcing required! </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="imp-links">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="">Terms of Use</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <p>&#124;</p>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="copyright">
                            <p>
                                &copy; Lorem, ipsum dolor | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur 2023
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="footer-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Home</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Web Design</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Social Media</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Branding</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Digital Marketing</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Influencer Marketing</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Projects</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Founders Talk</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>About Us</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/link-arrow.svg" alt="">
                                    <span>Work with us</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="footer-social-media">
                        <div class="sm-title">
                            <p>Follow us on</p>
                            <div class="images">
                                <a href=""><img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/tw.svg" alt=""></a>
                                <a href=""><img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/ig.svg" alt=""></a>
                                <a href=""><img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/ln.svg" alt=""></a>
                                <a href=""><img src="http://localhost/webpiz/images/dribbble.png" alt=""></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sm-email">
                            <p>Subscribe to know our latest blogs</p>
                            <form action="">
                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email address">
                                <button type="submit"><i class="bi bi-play-fill"></i></button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```